# How to use node-opcua Subscription priority?

Tags: node.js, opc, opc-ua, node-opcua

The Client subscription in node-opcua has an option called `priority`. It is a numerical field. I'm not able to understand whether subscription with `Priotity=1` will get higher priority than `Priority=10` or lower.

The default priority in source code is `1`. So it is the lowest, or the highest?
Which one will get preference, 1 or 10 or 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quote from the specification (v1.03 Part 4. Table 86)

> Indicates the relative priority of the Subscription. When more than
> one Subscription needs to send Notifications, the Server should
> dequeue a Publish request to the Subscription with the highest
> priority number (the bigger the number, the higher the priority). For
> Subscriptions with equal priority the Server should dequeue Publish
> requests in a round-robin fashion. When the keep-alive period expires
> for a Subscription it shall take precedence regardless of its
> priority, in order to prevent the Subscription from expiring.
>
> A Client that does not require special priority settings should set
> this value to zero.

I don't have very much experience how the servers actually support the priority in practice. It should play a role only when the server has a lot of data changes to be queued at the same time. For most cases you can ignore the parameter.

EDIT: The specifications are available from https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/specifications-unified-architecture (you will just need to register to the OPC Foundation web site to download them)

EDIT: The specifications for 1.04 are also available online now and the specific page that describe the priority parameter is https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Part4/5.13.2/

Comment: i guess "the bigger the number, the higher the priority" answers my question. Can you provide the link where you got the quote from?

Comment: Added the link to the answer